# Why isn't strtok correctly separating tokens?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm trying to adapt the following working code:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char input[10];   
    scanf("%s", input);
   char * pch;
   pch = strtok(input, " ");

 while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }   

   return 0;
}
```

If I input

```
test string to tokenize
```

I only get back

```
test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

Several problems with this:

1. The `%s` conversion specifier makes `scanf()` scan until the first whitespace. All you get in your buffer is `test`.
2. `test string to tokenize` won't fit in 10 characters.

Use `fgets()` instead with an appropriately sized buffer:

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

Another piece of advice: use `strtok_r()` instead of `strok()`, it's safer.

```
char *endp;
char *p = strtok_r(buf, " ", &endp);
while (p) {
    puts(p);
    p = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &endp);
}
```

Comment: strtok_r is reentrant, it's useful if you are writing a library or if you are using threads, otherwise strtok is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The `%s` conversion stops at the first whitespace.

Print your string *before* calling `strtok()` on it; it will be only `"test"`.

Also, as pointed out by [@Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707936/28169), you need to think about the buffer size you're using. 10 characters is very small.

Answer (score 2):

Attempting to store the string "test string to tokenize" in a `char[10]` is going to result in a buffer overflow. After that anything can happen. Increase the size of `input`:

```
char input[256];
```

Also, as noted by [@H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16708002/28169), you should use `fgets(...)` rather than `scanf("%s", ...)`, in order to avoid white space problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

This takes input until it encounters a space or `\n` .Infact you input only "test" to `strtok` as argument.

You need to use something like [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to input line with spaces.

Also, as pointed out by others, your buffer might overflow.